# Написать код по стандарту ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Как написать данный код по стандарту ES6?

```
<ul class="menu__ul">
    <li class="menu__li">
        <a class="menu__link" href="#">
            <span class="menu__title">about</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>



var menuUl = document.querySelector('.menu__ul')
var menuLink = document.getElementsByClassName('menu__link')

for (var i = 0; i < menuLink.length; i++) {

menuLink[i].onclick = function() { //click

    //remove class for all spans
    var menuTitle  = menuUl.querySelectorAll('.menu__title')
    for (i = 0; i < menuTitle.length; i++){
        menuTitle[i].classList.remove('menu__title--active')
    }

    this.querySelector('.menu__title').classList.add('menu__title--active') //add class
}

}
```

Comment: А такой стандарт есть? Может "с использованием фич ES6"?

Comment: @Other да, можно и так выразиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let menuUl = document.querySelector('.menu__ul');                  // Общий предок - менюшка в данном случае
let currentActive = document.querySelector('.menu__link--active'); // Текущий активный элемент; нужен для того, чтобы каждый раз не обходить все элементы

menuUl.addEventListener('click', function (e) { // Простенький
  let a = e.target.closest('a');                // Делегатор
  
  if(!a || !menuUl.contains(a)) return;         // См. https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation
  
  if(currentActive) {                                     // Если текущий элемен есть (сначала его нет, будет null)
    currentActive.classList.remove('menu__link--active'); // Убираем ему статус текущего
  }
  
  currentActive = a; // Теперь текущий - это тот, по которому кликнули
  
  a.classList.add('menu__link--active'); // Думаю очевидно
});
```

```css
.menu__link--active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu__ul">
  <li class="menu__li">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#">
      <span class="menu__title">about</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__li">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#">
      <span class="menu__title">test</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```